# How to handle the imageviews?

Tags: iphone

iam developing one application in that I use the three imageviews for a single row in the table.For first two images loaded successfully.At the time of loading the third image ,image will become black.Si please tell me how to handle this one.Below one is the code of imageview declaration.

```
     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        UITableViewCell *cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc]init] autorelease];
         tableview1.separatorStyle=UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    if(indexPath.row==0)
    {
        image1=[[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 8, 90, 90)]autorelease];
        image1.frame=CGRectMake(12, 8, 90, 90);
        [image1.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
        [image1.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
        [image1.layer setCornerRadius:1.0f];
        image1.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        image1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        image1.tag=1;

        [image1 setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
        if([[odrdata stringForKey:@"keyTo1Image"] isEqualToString:@""])  
        {

        }
        else 
        {
    image1.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[odrdata stringForKey:@"keyTo1Image"]];

        }
        [cell.contentView addSubview:image1];

    image2=[[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(114, 8, 90, 90)]autorelease];
        image2.frame=CGRectMake(114, 8, 90, 90);
        [image2.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
        [image2.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
        [image2.layer setCornerRadius:1.0f];
        image2.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        image2.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        image2.tag=1;

        [image2 setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
        if([[odrdata stringForKey:@"keyTo2Image"] isEqualToString:@""])  
        {

        }
        else 
        {
    image2.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[odrdata stringForKey:@"keyTo2Image"]];

        }
        [cell.contentView addSubview:image2];

    image3=[[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(216, 8, 90, 90)]autorelease];
        image3.frame=CGRectMake(216, 8, 90, 90);
        [image3.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
        [image3.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
        [image3.layer setCornerRadius:1.0f];
        image3.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        image3.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        image3.tag=3;

        [image3 setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
        if([[odrdata stringForKey:@"keyTo3Image"] isEqualToString:@""])  
        {

        }
        else 
        {
    image3.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[odrdata stringForKey:@"keyTo3Image"]];
        }
        [cell.contentView addSubview:image3];

fsttapGesture=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlefstTap:)];
        fsttapGesture.delegate=self;
        [image1 addGestureRecognizer:fsttapGesture];

sndtapGesture=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlesndTap:)];
        sndtapGesture.delegate=self;
        [image2 addGestureRecognizer:sndtapGesture];

trdtapGesture=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handletrdTap:)];
        trdtapGesture.delegate=self;
        [image3 addGestureRecognizer:trdtapGesture];

        return cell;
    }
```

}

Comment: I only see one image view being created here. Where are the other two you're talking about?

Comment: Like this another two images will be added to cell at different places in horizontal manner.

Comment: Please show all of the relevant code for all image views. Otherwise, it's nearly impossible to tell what's going wrong.

Comment: is the image3 ok? try changing its content with the one from image1 or image2 first to be sure. (i.e. set keyTo2Image instead of keyTo3Image)

Comment: image 3 is ok.It diaplay the image of image1 or image2

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the file exists for `keyTo3Image`? What's probably happening is that the image view can't find an image at the path you specify in that string. Check that it actually points to a file. To verify this, change the `backgroundColor` property of `image3` and see if it changes:

```
image3.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

If it changes to red, then that means the image couldn't be found so it's just displaying an empty image view.

Comment: It display the image after perform the changes.